# How to reduce the size of the app in android

Tags: android

1. It deals with  SQlite database, two fragments, around 10 activities,
   31 .java files.

   2. No interet services used. Access storage photos,
      music and videos.
   3. I store all the paths of media files in database.
   4. My colleague said it should be around 5MB.
   5. But it is    10 times more than that...

   What might be the reasons?? What should i Do?

Comment: Maybe you use lots of libraries.

Comment: photos,music,videos ..better compress their sizes

Comment: I think that it should be even lass than 5 mb. I can't imagine how you increased it's size to 50 mb. You are definately doing something wrong. But only you know what you do. You didn't post any info of your app.

Comment: compiling with debug apk might have caused it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reduce the included Resources (Drawables, Mipmaps, ...) as much a possible, remove unused libraries and dependencies from the Gradle build configuration, and last but not least, make sure you're compiling the release .apk since the debug one is normally much bigger

Comment: Most likely, debug apk's don't have ProGuard applied during the build and are usually bigger

Answer (score 1):

1 - Use ProGaurd (Facility provided by android)

2 - Remove "Log" from your app wherever you use

3 - compress your images using below sites

For PNG -  http://www.compresspng.com

For JPEG - http://www.compressjpeg.com

4 - Remove unused imports, xml, java, drawable, string

5 - Try to reuse layout or class as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

There are few points.

1. Remove unused resources (images, xml, classes etc.)
2. Remove unused libraries (jar, gradle dependencies)
3. Compress your code (Use proguard https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)
4. Use light weight images for background (use image compress)

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce image sizes in drawable it will help you

use 9Patch Resizer
it will help you to make drawble images of any size with reduced size

Answer (score 0):

1. use apk analyzer tool to analyze your apk, it can be found under "Build" menu and named as "Analyze APK..." from this you should get a clear idea about what is taking up space [image: it will look something like this]
2. try to use .webp or SVG instead of .png/.jpg in drawables
3. remove unnecessary libraries.
4. for release apk use Proguard (not necessary in debug builds)

Comment: I just gone thru Analyze apk, it shows as raw size 6MB, and download size-5.6 MB....\

Comment: then how can your app be 50MB?

Comment: also try disabling instant run and then generate the apk

Answer (score 0):

Steps for Reducing APK Size

1. First Check the Size of Your res folder.
2. Use tinypng(https://tinypng.com) to compress all the images in res folder.
3. Use Proguard if will decrease app size by 1MB(approx.)
4. If you have used External library like fcm or google play services, then    choose selected features you required in app.

   ```
     Google+   com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1
   ```

   Google Account Login    com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1
   Google Actions, Base Client Library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1
   Google Address API  com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1
   Firebase App Indexing   com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1
   Google Analytics    com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1
   Google Awareness    com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:10.0.1
   Google Cast com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.0.1
   Google Cloud Messaging  com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1
   Google Drive    com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.0.1
   Google Fit  com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.0.1
   Google Location and Activity Recognition    com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1
   Google Maps com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1
   Google Mobile Ads   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1
   Google Places   com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1
   Mobile Vision   com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1
   Google Nearby   com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.0.1
   Google Panorama Viewer  com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:10.0.1
   Google Play Game services   com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.1
   SafetyNet   com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:10.0.1
   Android Pay com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.0.1
   Android Wear    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1